# Installed Python, Anaconda and Juypter but not working

Tags: python

I have successfully installed

> Python 3.8
>
> Pycharm
>
> Anaconda
>
> Jupyter notebook

Somehow it is not working

Do I have to uninstall and start again?

I am new to all this and very nervous.

https://snipboard.io/GOMx81.jpg.  -

https://snipboard.io/QZ12Ju.jpg

Comment: @Keldorn He clearly meant anaconda. @nicola Did you activate the conda environment before you started trying to use it. To activate run `conda acivate` afterwards you should be able to access all the goodies that come with anacaonda

Comment: Welcome to SO, take time to read, accept to go slower, questions and frustrations are part of the process. It is normal it takes time to learn when you are new to something. Also take time to consider writing a comprehensive question if you aim someone helps you. Consider the fact that your problem description is not sufficient to narrow what is you problem. Cheers

Comment: Speaking of typo @maestro.inc, you should add a `t` to `conda activate`. Plus an environment name?
@nicola The question is too vague to be answered. "I have successfully installed", how? "Somehow it is not working", how?

Comment: @Keldom Nope, `conda activate` activates the default anaconda environment which comes with it by default. You could create your own virtual environment with the conda environment which is what you are refering to(and is generally good practice) but not what i am referring to